# Problem in inserting images in the template engines

Tags: express, pug

trying to add some images in my pug file but images are not showing when the file is opened in the server . also tried in the handlebars but there also images are not showing then converted those files in the html format than the images appeared

Comment: Without code example we will be not able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the images are served by the server and the src attribute is correct

Comment: yes those all are correct because when I converted the files into html . the files started to show